# Long boot time Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04

My boot time is too long. I used the `systemd-analyze blame` command and here's the result:

```
dimitrios@dimitrios-A15:~/Downloads$ systemd-analyze blame
     1min 4.487s apt-daily.service
         22.627s dev-sda4.device
         11.789s systemd-udevd.service
          9.863s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          5.549s apache2.service
          5.411s ModemManager.service
          5.028s grub-common.service
          4.334s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          3.899s accounts-daemon.service
          3.563s thermald.service
          3.413s NetworkManager.service
          3.084s iio-sensor-proxy.service
          2.770s vboxdrv.service
          2.238s keyboard-setup.service
          2.089s irqbalance.service
          1.961s binfmt-support.service
          1.940s quota.service
          1.865s bluetooth.service
          1.802s dev-hugepages.mount
          1.802s sys-kernel-debug.mount
          1.711s dev-mqueue.mount
          1.618s systemd-logind.service
          1.596s gpu-manager.service
          1.574s console-setup.service
          1.516s udisks2.service
          1.480s colord.service
          1.480s upower.service
          1.448s rsyslog.service
          1.334s ofono.service
          1.304s ondemand.service
          1.303s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.297s speech-dispatcher.service
          1.297s console-kit-log-system-start.service
          1.269s laptop-mode.service
          1.268s pppd-dns.service
          1.246s systemd-user-sessions.service
          1.218s avahi-daemon.service
          1.193s systemd-journald.service
          1.039s wpa_supplicant.service
           985ms apport.service                                                                                                                                         
           964ms console-kit-daemon.service                                                                                                                             
           938ms networking.service                                                                                                                                     
           911ms polkitd.service                                                                                                                                        
           852ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                                                                                                           
           839ms systemd-rfkill.service                                                                                                                                 
           725ms setvtrgb.service                                                                                                                                       
           669ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                                                                                                            
           590ms lm-sensors.service
```

How can I speed things up?

Comment: What is /dev/sda4?  It eats up a full 22 seconds.

Comment: Also apt-daily.service takes over one minute.  That surprises me: daily tasks get run once a day, but that's mostly cleaning up logs, etc...

Comment: It's the partition where ubuntu is installed

Comment: Ok, that was my guess, but I wanted to verify.  Is your hard disk ok?  Have you checked its SMARTS status?  Disks that are dying usually become slower, before completely dying.  (If it's an SSD, that does not apply).  Given daily also does a lot of IO and the system has to wait a long time for sda4, my gut feeling is: disk is dying.  But it's a guess, so please check the smart status of your disks.  (Disks application, select disk /dev/sda, "Menu Icon" (Hamburger icon), SMART Data & Self Tests.  You can eventually click "start self-test", and do "short"-

Comment: Overall assessment : Disk is OK
self-assessment : Threshold not exceeded

Comment: Let it run the self-test, but it probably isn't the disk then.  Perhaps someone else has an idea.

Comment: That was the result of the test. May i run the "slow" test?

Comment: You can, but it takes an eternity and usually doesn't give much more information.  At least to my experience.

Comment: Is /dev/sda4 an NTFS partition? what is the output of `sudo blkid`?

Comment: /dev/sda1: UUID="f42ad7b1-3b96-4027-8f5a-3cbcda83a5bf" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="969b1d5e-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="recovery" UUID="84424EA8424E9F34" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="969b1d5e-02"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="76765FC1765F80B3" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="969b1d5e-03"
/dev/sda4: UUID="aea974e6-7b2a-460f-bebd-4454829232d4" TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="969b1d5e-04"

Comment: @AnastasiosPapaspyrou, Could you add the output of `systemctl status dev-sda4.device` may be fsck was run on boot before remount RW.

Comment: My boot times suddenly got a lot longer when I upgraded to a new (K)ubuntu version a year or two ago (16.04 maybe?). It seemed like booting up and logging started taking 2 or 3 minutes. My laptop was not even a year old, but the hard drive was a relatively slow 5400 RPM hard drive. I upgraded to an SSD drive for $80 and now my boot times are under 10 seconds from power on to the login screen and under 5 seconds from login till you get to the desktop. I would suggest upgrading to an SSD drive.

Comment: I'm with @DanielMeyer - switched all the Ubuntu systems to SSD, including the laptop.  Also did it with my Win7 NAS.  Rather than explain it to people I just say I have "lightning drives" - My main server boots faster than my phone.  Of course it also has a HDD in it.  So I am also focused on this dev/sda4.  That should be a partition on the boot drive.  BOTTOM LINE:  MAKE A BACKUP  - have you done this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the *ix-ish systems I've seen, output the progress of the startup process, by resources and daemons.  Like a million times something like

```
    `[xyz] successfully started on abc status blah at ....`
```

How does your system reboot?  Somewhere your startup scripts must be set to non-verbose.  If you can undo that, that could give you your direct clue.  Anyone more knowledgeable?

Looking at them start after like 15 years though, I had to say even at their fastest they are doing much less useful stuff and taking a lot more time :D anyway.

Comment: ahhh.  just realized the question was asked over six months ago!

Comment: Care to give us a clue where to find it?  (Of course, I prefer the SSD boot drive solution.)